# Stock Messaging App Locks and is Slow

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S4 (from iPhone) and still trying to make the transition and learn all of the new features.

One issue I have is with the stock messaging app. It completely freezes up at times. I cannot back out of a conversation thread. Messages do not go out. Eventually I will receive a message saying this app has frozen do I want to wait or close. Finally the messaging app doesn't load at all and I have to reboot the phone to get the app back.

What can I do to solve this problem and have the messaging app functioning smoothly and properly?

Notes:

- I am running 4.2.2.
- Memory is 8+ GB available
- Only a few apps are running (I know how to close open apps)

Comment: Do you notice if the issues might occur at times where you're not getting good Cell/Data coverage? Just a hunch but the freezes and hold-ups might be due to lack of signal to communicate back and forth...The app shouldn't be responding like it is though, but there you have it. 

You might want to try finding an alternate messaging app in the Play store to see if you get better performance/reliability.

Comment: You can install third party messaging apps from play store.

Comment: @Namuna - Coverage seems okay. Do you have any messaging apps to recommend? I am new to Android.

Comment: [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) is pretty popular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are coming from an iPhone and looking for a better messaging app, check out [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) and use an iPhone theme.

This app allows you to customize several things while still looking very similar to the iPhone's messaging interface. I always install Go SMS over the default messaging app and you might just want to give it a try, especially since you are coming from iOS. There are other plugins that are all free that allow you to view iOS emojis and other cools things like that.

Let me know if you still have the same issues with this app as well.

btw, congrats on smartly making the switch ;)